# Android Device Monitor is not opening in android studio on mac

Tags: android, android-device-monitor

When I try to open android device monitor in android studio it's showing below error

[image]

Below is my log file. Can anyone suggest me soltion?

```
   !SESSION 2017-01-26 16:39:56.119 -----------------------------------------------
 eclipse.buildId=unknown
 java.version=1.8.0_101
 java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
 BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
 Framework arguments:  -keyring /Users/Puja Dudhat/.eclipse_keyring -    showlocation
 Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -data @noDefault -keyring   /Users/Puja Dudhat/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation

 !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-01-26 16:39:56.852
 !MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609/@4 not found.

 !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-01-26 16:39:56.855
 !MESSAGE Bundle     reference:file:org.apache.jasper.glassfish_2.2.2.v201205150955.jar@4 not found.

 !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-01-26 16:39:56.855
 !MESSAGE Bundle   reference:file:org.apache.lucene.core_2.9.1.v201101211721.jar@4 not found.

 !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-01-26 16:39:56.873
 !MESSAGE Bundle  reference:file:org.eclipse.help.base_3.6.101.v201302041200.jar@4 not found.

 !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-01-26 16:39:56.874
 !MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.help.ui_3.5.201.v20130108- 092756.jar@4 not found.

 !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-01-26 16:39:56.874
 !MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.help.webapp_3.6.101.v20130116-182509.jar@4 not found.

 !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-01-26 16:39:56.876
 !MESSAGE Bundle    reference:file:org.eclipse.jetty.server_8.1.3.v20120522.jar@4 not found.
```

Reply

Comment: can you open that log file and see what's in there?

Comment: Ohh I didn't check that. let me open

Comment: I posted log above. Can you please tell me what's wrong with it

Comment: Try to re install Android Studio.

Comment: Will it solve my problem ?

Comment: I had the same error just after I deleted manually my Android Device Monitor files installed from Apple (the link: https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_GB)

Comment: I also got this problem on mac .. How to solve it ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to install the latest Java JDK version, I had the same error.

Comment: This solved it completely. I even don't have to launch the monitor from the CL; it opens fine from Android studio.