# Android Device Monitor is not opening in Mac

Tags: java, android, macos, android-device-monitor

I need to view and edit the shared preferences for my app. When I try to open the Android Device Monitor from my Android Studios (Tools > Android > Android Device Monitor) it gives the following error:

[image]

When I open that log file, the given error is as follows:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B43t-lgy1BmXWjMtTjE3ZGI5TlE/view?usp=sharing

I found a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41885612/android-device-monitor-is-not-opening-in-android-studio-on-mac) where the suggested fix was to update the Java SDK. However my Java SDK is already updated:

[image]

I also thought maybe the device monitor was not installed, but it is.
What is going on and how do I get my ADM back?

Comment: I tried few versions of Java 8 but only 1.8.0_151 works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, that is Android Monitor could't find Java8. Installing with brew didn't help, but installing from [Oracle dmg](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, following solution worked for me I hope it also helps you, =>
uninstalling the JDK and then again downloaded the JDK 8 from Oracle.
install JDK 8 according to instruction.
To make sure JDK is installed successfully write following command in terminal: /usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7

then set a path of JDK in Android Studio by doing the following
Go to file -> project Structure -> JDK path.